# is it possible to get time in box charts in chartjs?

Tags: charts, chart.js, ng2-charts, ngx-charts

Pls find the below image for time in box chart, is it possible to get same UI in chartjs or ng2-charts?
Kindly help here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulclH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. For the round data points you can use a buble chart and the either use the annotation plugin ( https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation ) or write a custom plugin to draw the box

Comment: Hi LeeLenalee, Thanks for response. Pls give me the custom plugin code, i'm not aware of write customize plugin to draw the box. Kindly help me here. Or Share the Same UI url as well.

Comment: Kindly help me here LeeLenalee.

Comment: You can take a look at this fiddle on how to use the plugin api to draw the lines on the canvas like you want, you might want to make them look nicer and maby not hardcoded like this since they wont stay at the correct spot on the canvas on resize. https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/3d4p9mgk/17/